# ASP.NET Menu loaded from database

Tags: asp.net, menu, sitemap, provider

I need to load an aspmenu from a database table. I'd like it to work as XmlSiteMap provider, I mean, only accesing the database when it changes, otherwise no.

How acan I do this, by a CustomSiteMapProvider? Any samples?

I'm using RadMenu which lets you connect directly to a database by using an ObjectDataSource, but the menu is loaded on every request so is not very good for performance.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you really noticed it being bad performance?  If you are using an ObjectDataSource, why can't you implement caching in your custom DAL method that connects to the database?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radmenu-getting-started.html

There are a lot of good-links off of the tutorial.  Besides that, if you want the menu to not be loaded on every request, then look to assigning the datasoure in the onload event, instead of the mark-up.